# how to replace values with previous when conditions are met?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, iterator, grouping, conditional-statements

I am trying to make a denormalize dataframe based on a report I receive. I need to assign records to a group and this group comes from one row with random text and nan's in between group designations. how do I rewrite these row valueswhen conditions are met? The loop I have written seems to only write over the next value when the condition is met and does not do this until the next condition is met. Please see the example of my data and code below. Essentially I need the rows to be either Primary, Secondary, or any other group I decide but it must run until the next designated group is hit.

Current Data:

```
    Primary
    Week#
    1
    nan
    nan
    nan
    2
    nan
    nan
    nan
    Secondary
    Week#
    1
    nan
    nan
    nan
    2
    nan
    nan
    nan
```

Code:

```
for index, obj in enumerate(df['col0']):
    l = len(df['col0'])
    if obj == 'Primary':
        if index > 0:
            previous = df['col0'][index - 1]
        if index < (l - 1):
            next_ = df['col0'][index + 1]
            next_ = obj
            print (next_, obj)

    if obj == 'Secondary':
        if index > 0:
            previous = df['col0'][index - 1]
        if index < (l - 1):
            next_ = df['col0'][index + 1]
            next_ = obj
            print (next_, obj)
```

Expected Output:

```
Primary
Primary
Primary
Primary
Primary
Primary
Primary
Primary
Primary
Primary
Secondary
Secondary
Secondary
Secondary
Secondary
Secondary
Secondary
Secondary
Secondary
Secondary
```

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand what you're trying to achieve, but two things stand out: 1. You're assigning a value to `previous` without ever using it, and you're assigning to `next_` twice in succession, so `next_ = df['col0'][index + 1]` is always overwritten by `next_ = obj`

Comment: I'd recommend that in your question you separate your example data from your code. I assume they're from different files, but right now the example data part looks like malformed Python code. And perhaps you could include the output you get, and the output you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more pandorable way to do this would be to keep only the values you care about and forward-fill them for the places you don't.  For example:

```
df["col0_cleaned"] = df["col0"].where(df["col0"].isin(["Primary", "Secondary"])).ffill()
```

If we take this in steps, it becomes more clear what's going on:

```
df["isin"] = df["col0"].isin(["Primary", "Secondary"])
df["where"] = df["col0"].where(df["col0"].isin(["Primary", "Secondary"]))
df["ffill"] = df["col0"].where(df["col0"].isin(["Primary", "Secondary"])).ffill()
```

which gives me:

```
In [350]: df
Out[350]: 
         col0   isin      where      ffill
0     Primary   True    Primary    Primary
1       Week#  False        NaN    Primary
2           1  False        NaN    Primary
3         nan  False        NaN    Primary
4         nan  False        NaN    Primary
5         nan  False        NaN    Primary
6           2  False        NaN    Primary
7         nan  False        NaN    Primary
8         nan  False        NaN    Primary
9         nan  False        NaN    Primary
10  Secondary   True  Secondary  Secondary
11      Week#  False        NaN  Secondary
12          1  False        NaN  Secondary
13        nan  False        NaN  Secondary
14        nan  False        NaN  Secondary
15        nan  False        NaN  Secondary
16          2  False        NaN  Secondary
17        nan  False        NaN  Secondary
18        nan  False        NaN  Secondary
19        nan  False        NaN  Secondary
```